# HP Smart Document Scan Software supporting Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, hp, sharepoint-2010

We're proposing a solutions to use HP scanner to scan documents directly into our client's SharePoint 2010 server. But according to [HP Smart Document Scan Software Brochure](http://www.hp.com/sbso/special/printing/hp-smart-document-scan-software.pdf) it only mentioned supports for SP2003 & SP2007. Is there by any chance it will work with SP2010? Does anyone has an idea if HP will be releasing a version with supports for SP2010 within 6 months from now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot find any evidence of any support for Sharepoint 2010.  Did you contact HP and ask them?

Comment: The HP support is not very helpful over here. Anyway, the proposal was  submitted. It normally takes at least 6 months to a year before approval, so by then it should have the newer release. Or else we can use third party solutions. Tq